# Allow user to set up pdf file name in C# windows forms (iTextSharp)

Tags: pdf, c#

I want to alow user to enter his own file name, just like save file dialog and stream (Example: `Stream s = File.Open(sfdPdf.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew)`

Here is my code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
                {
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save("Image.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }

                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, bounds.Left, bounds.Right, bounds.Top, bounds.Bottom);
                PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("ImageTest.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                doc.Open();
                iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Image.jpeg");
                doc.Add(image);
                doc.Close();


        }
```

I want the part "ImateTest.pdf" to be named as the user want

`PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("ImageTest.pdf", FileMode.Create));`

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .net save file dialog.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 Stream myStream ;
 SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

 saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
 saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
 saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
     {
         // Code to write the stream goes here.
         myStream.Close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: It would be better to give the source link then quote the code as web pages can move, (especially msdn ones as MS decides "everybody" will be using our new framework").